# URL / URI encoding in R

Tags: r, parsing, post, encoding, get

I have to request an API with an URL encoding according to RFC 3986, knowing that I have accented characters in my query.

For instance, this argument :

```
quel écrivain ?
```

should be encoded like this:

```
quel%20%C3%A9crivain%20%3F%0D%0A
```

Unfortunately, when I use URLencode, encoding, url_encode, or curlEscape, I have the resulting encoding:

```
URLencode("quel écrivain ?")
[1] "quel%20%E9crivain%20?"
```

The problem is on accented letters: for instance "é" is converted into "%E9" instead of "%C3%A9"...

I struggle with this URL encoding without finding any issue... As I don't have the hand on the API, I don't know how it handles the encoding.

A weird thing is that using POST instead of GET leads to a response in which word with accent are cutted into 2 different lines :

```
"1\tquel\tquel\tDET\tDET\tGender=Masc|Number=Sing\t5\tdet\t0\t_\n4\t<U+FFFD>\t<U+FFFD>\tSYM\tSYM\t_\t5\tcompound\t0\t_\n5\tcrivain\tcrivain\
```

As you can see, "écrivain" is splitted into `"<U+FFFD>"` (which is an ASCII encoding of "é") and `"crivain"`.

I become mad with this encoding problem, if a brilliant mind could help me I would be very gratefull!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think I am a brilliant mind, but I still have a possible solution for you. After using `URLencode()` it seems that your accented characters are converted into the trailing part of their unicode representation preceeded by a `%`. To convert your characters into readable characters you might turn them into "real unicode" and use the package `stringi` to make them readable. For your single string the solution worked on my machine, at least. I hope it also works for you.

Please note that I have introduced a `%` character at the end of your string to demonstrate that below `gsub` command should work in any case.

You might have to adapt the replacement pattern `\\u00` to also cover unicode patterns that have more than the last two positions filled with something but `0`, if this is relevant in your case.

```
library(stringi)
str <- "quel écrivain ?"
str <- URLencode(str)
#"quel%20%E9crivain%20?"
#replacing % by a single \ backslash to directly get correct unicode representation
#does not work since it is an escape character, therefore "\\"
str <- gsub("%", paste0("\\", "u00"), str , fixed = T)
#[1] "quel\\u0020\\u00E9crivain\\u0020?"
#since we have double escapes, we need the unescape function from stringi
#which recognizes double backslash as single backslash for the conversion
str <- stri_unescape_unicode(str)
#[1] "quel écrivain ?"
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, I didn't do exactly the same but the `stri_unescape_unicode` was the good function to call!
1. I first applied the `stri_escape_unicode` to the body of my POST query,
2. Then I used the `stri_unescape_unicode` function to the response content, and the encoding was ok!

Comment: I am glad I could point you to a working solution. Someone once said that "Encodings are only there to drive programmers mad" :-).

Comment: I couldn't agree more ;)

Answer (score 11):

Set `reserved = TRUE`

i.e.

```
your_string <- "quel écrivain ?"

URLencode(your_string, reserved = TRUE)
# [1] "quel%20%C3%A9crivain%20%3F"
```